# S3 Static Website directory index redirect with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

With an S3 static site, I am able to hit /directory and it will serve up the index.html file inside the directory. Once I add the S3 bucket as a CloudFront origin, I instead get an Access Denied message.

How can I replicate this S3 functionality in CloudFront?

Comment: check your CORS and permissions on the s3 bucket

Comment: I'm allowing all CORS and CF has s3:GetObject perms to the bucket via a bucket policy.

Comment: Note that this issue can arise when building a Middleman site using Directory Indexes, deploying to S3 and using CloudFront to distribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to setup S3 static site hosting and use CloudFront to point to it as a remote origin website instead of an S3 bucket.